# How does this array copy work?

Tags: c++, c++11

I randomly wrote functions that takes array reference and return an array, and initializes a new array from the old one:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T& return_arr(T& arr) {
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    double a[] = {1,2,4.5,9};
    auto x = return_arr(a);
    a[2] = 5;
    cout << x[2] << endl;
    //x.dummy_error(); // If this one is uncommented, the compiler says x is a double*
    auto&& y = return_arr(a);
    a[3] = 10;
    cout << y[3] << endl;
    //y.dummy_error(); // If this one is uncommented, the compiler says y is a double[4]

    return 0;
}
```

Why `x` got decayed to a pointer? The function is supposed to return a `T&` and `auto` should initialize a type T right?

Also why `y` is a `double[4]`? `auto&&` should perfectly forward the type and y should be a `double [4] &` right?

Can someone explain why all of these are happening?

Comment: `auto y&&`? Did you mean `auto&& y`?

Comment: a[] is in fact pointer to double.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are wondering about, not code that is **close** to what you are wondering about.  I took the liberty of moving that `&&` which I believe is a typo to being beside the `auto` -- if I am wrong, please revert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass or return an array by value in C++. Sorry---you just can't.

```
auto x = return_arr(a);
```

In this call, `T` is deduced as `double [4]`. So `return_arr` takes *reference to array* and it also returns *reference to array*. So this call really does the same thing as

```
auto x = a;
```

`x` is deduced as `double*`. This is because `auto` uses the same rules for type deduction as templates, and a non-reference template type parameter is deduced as pointer when the argument is an array. In other words, decay occurs here, as you would normally expect.

```
auto&& y = return_arr(a);
```

In this case, because of the reference, `y` is deduced as reference to array, and decay does not occur. So this is really the same as

```
double (&y)[4] = a;
```

and this is a reference initialization. Again, the array is not copied.

If you want to copy arrays, use `memset`, `std::copy`, or a container such as `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: I used `y.dummy_error()`, and the compiler says `error: request for member ‘dummy_error’ in ‘y’, which is of non-class type ‘double [4]’`

Comment: Look at my second last sentence in the question

Comment: @texasbruce That's because expressions in C++ never have reference type. After `y` is initialized, it *is* a `double [4]`; its "referenceness" can't be detected by the type system. However, `std::is_same<decltype(y), double(&)[4]>::value` will be true, and `std::is_same<decltype(y), double[4]>::value` will be false. Try it.

Comment: @texasbruce You are conflating `y`, a variable of type `double (&)[4]`, with the expression `y` resulting from evaluating that variable which has type `double[4]` and value category lvalue.